# Diagnosing RAID partition slowness

Tags: windows, performance, raid, partition

This involves:

- RAID 10
- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Two logical drive partitions

The server in question has four drives in a RAID 10 configuration, as well as two in RAID 0. The RAID 0 is used for the OS and is behaving itself. The RAID 10 is divided into two logical drives, D and L. The L drive performs as expected, but we're seeing very poor performance on D, despite it being part of the same RAID.

How do I go about diagnosing the problem, and hopefully fixing it?

EDIT: As it turns out, I was misinformed. The L drive is partitioned off the wrong array. This solves the peculiarity of the problem, leaving a separate array slowness issue that can be diagnosed through conventional means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use perfmon to take a look at the counters for the underlying physical disk. Most interesting values are idle time, length of write queue, length of read queue and the service time (avg seconds / transfer). [This Technet blog article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/vipulshah/archive/2006/11/30/understanding-perfmon-counters-while-troubleshooting-sql-server-performance-issues.aspx) is giving some rough orientation on how to interpret the perfmon disk counter values and find bottlenecks.

Comment: Used a different tool to get it, but this is actually the data that sent me here. sec/transfer averages .09 vs .001 on the D and L drives, respectively.

Comment: The "logical disk" values are mostly meaningless as they are just an artificial separation of the physical disk parameters. Could you post a performance graph or at least values for the given four params for your physical disk?

Comment: Getting the data together to reply to this showed I was misinformed about the drive configuration. Thanks for helping me get to this point.

Answer (score 0):

You might also check to ensure the "D" volume is healthy. Checking in on its fragmentation may not hurt as well..

Comment: I checked this earlier, and it has 4% fragmentation and comes up clean with every test I know including checkdisk.

Comment: Any significant difference in use or data being stored between D & L?

Comment: Yes, D has about 4x the reads and 2x the writes as L. The relevant metric, though, is that the average for reads is over 90x slower on D. This is a recent change as these two used to be nearly identical.

Comment: The read/write differences are also compounded with the RAID "hits" as well. Any way to "quieting" down D for a "sanity" check?

Comment: Took a while to schedule the downtime for it, but I'll be testing this tonight.